# Looking up an array index by value in bash 3.x

Tags: arrays, bash

I call this script with: `./script_name 604`

```
#!/bin/bash

switchedChannel=($1)
channelArray=('108' '162' '163' '604' '141' '113')

for array_item in "${channelArray[@]}"; do
    if [[ $array_item == ${switchedChannel[0]} ]] then
        "$array_item MATCHES"
    fi
done
```

Is there a way to get the index of the array_item that matches (or otherwise get the position of the matched item in the array) without simply using a var as a counter and using this to do the iteration?

There will always be a match, but the array values are unique so there's only one match.

(I am asking because I need then to do something with the array items that are NOT matched, so my thinking is to remove the matched one from the array.  I could move the unmatched items to a new array which is fine for a short list, but it would be preferable to terminate the loop as soon as the match is made.)

Comment: `switchedChannel` is not an array.

Comment: As an aside, if your values are all positive numbers, you don't need associative arrays -- a sparse indexed array will do.

Comment: BTW -- `switchedChannel=( $1 )` is pretty substantially buggy -- if your program were started with `./yourProg '*'`, you'd get a list of files in the local directory in your array; if `IFS=0` and the user passed `109`, you'd get an array where the first entry were `1` and the second entry were `9`; etc. What's your actual goal here? If you really do want to read a string into an array, the general Right Way to do it is with something like `read -r -a switchedChannels` -- though it's not obvious why that would be the intent in this case.

Comment: Inexperience is the truth!  It should not be an array, but a var to hold the search string.

Comment: In that case, `switchedChannel=$1` will suffice, and `"$switchedChannel"` on lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"${!array[@]}"` will iterate over indices, rather than values.

```
#!/bin/bash

switchedChannel=$1
channelArray=('108' '162' '163' '604' '141' '113')

for array_idx in "${!channelArray[@]}}"; do
    array_item=${channelArray[$array_idx]}
    if [[ $array_item = "$switchedChannel" ]] then
        "$array_item MATCHES at index $array_idx"
    fi
done
```

---

That said, for your use case -- where anything you're doing a lookup by is a non-negative integer -- you can do better:

```
declare -a channelArray=( [108]=1 [162]=2 [163]=3 [604]=4 [141]=5 [113]=6 )
echo "${channelArray[$switchedChannel]}"
```

This creates a *sparse array* where the keys are numbers `108`, `162`, etc.; and the values are `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.

Comment: Thank you.  I like the second approach best.  I think the first one is using array_idx as a var for iteration isn't it?

Comment: Correct, `array_idx` is what we're putting each index into as we iterate over it.

Comment: Would you do me one more favour and just explain what's happening with the second lookup please?  (It's getting the desired result, but I would like to learn more)

Comment: In the second case, what we've created is a *sparse* array. When you run `channelArray=('108' '162' '163' '604' '141' '113')`, what it's actually declaring looks like: `declare -a channelArray='([0]="108" [1]="162" [2]="163" [3]="604" [4]="141" [5]="113")'` -- so your indexes/keys are 0-5, and the larger numbers are the values. By contrast, the second approach turns this on its head, and creates an "array" where the *keys* are 108, 162, etc., and the *values* are 1-6 (adding one so the not-found case is distinct).

Comment: Aha!  Very useful.  Thanks again.